# Permalinks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, permalinks

Can anyone point me to some good resources on how to implement PERMA links in ASP.NET?

I've done a couple google searches but haven't found anything that like authoritative or definitive.

Comment: Have you considered marking my answer as *the* answer? It seems you have recieved the information you needed...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of a Permalink Generator for ASP.NET MVC in Brad Wilson's [Big Boy MVC Series](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/09/the-big-boy-mvc-series-part-23-baby-got-postbacks-a-preamble/) - even if you're not using the MVC framework, it probably can give you a good idea of what you need to do to generate permalinks.

Comment: @Brent: Yes, the blog seems to have moved (or just shut down) since I posted this 7 years ago. The Internet Archives [have a copy cached, though](http://web.archive.org/web/20110322111406/http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/09/the-big-boy-mvc-series-part-23-baby-got-postbacks-a-preamble/).